# Problem plotting geometries in Choropleth map using plotly

Tags: python, mapbox, plotly

I am trying to plot census level data and geometries to plotly mapbox. While I am able to plot the base map, the colored polygons used to represent spatial data are missing.

```
import pandas as pd 
import geopandas as gpd
import mapbox
from plotly import graph_objs as go
from plotly.graph_objs import *

df_geo = gpd.read_file('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kevalshah90/StroomWeb/23ef45e3d4da98ec0d6cae91842174411a403692/uscensusgeo.geojson')


import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure(go.Choroplethmapbox(geojson=df_geo['geometry'].to_json(), 
                                    locations=df_geo['TRACTCE'], 
                                    z=df_geo['ALAND'],
                                    colorscale="Viridis", 
                                    zmin=df_geo['ALAND'].min(), 
                                    zmax=df_geo['ALAND'].max(), 
                                    marker_line_width=0))

fig.update_layout(mapbox_style="light", 
                  mapbox_accesstoken=token,
                  mapbox_zoom=3, 
                  mapbox_center = {"lat": 37.0902, "lon": -95.7129},
                  margin={"r":0,"t":0,"l":0,"b":0})

fig.update_layout()
fig.show()
```

The colored polygons are missing from the map above.

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Unexpected error while fetching from {"type": "FeatureCollection", "features": [{"id": "0", "type": "Feature", "properties": {}, "geometry": {"type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [[[-81.375782, 28.411135], [-81.372696, 28.421524], [-81.368127, 28.43621], [-81.366996, 28.440684], [-81.366866, 28.445807], [-81.364976, 28.4458], [-81.361445, 28.445845], [-81.358309, 28.446668], [-81.350651, 28.450405], [-81.351092, 28.449687], [-81.349923, 28.449939],
```

[image]

Comment: Coordinates in your GeoJSON are in CRS EPSG:4269, which means `[lat, lng]` coordinates order, but standard for GeoJSON is `[lng, lat]` order.

Comment: @TomazicM can you specify how do I update the coordinates to standard GeoJSON crs in python?

Comment: @TomazicM I have included the error I am seeing in browser console. It looks like the coordinates are in `[lng, lat]` order.

Answer (score 2):

This is happening for two reasons:

1. The `locations` argument is pointing to a column that does not match your GeoJSON's 'id's.
2. The `geojson` argument expects a dictionary and you are passing a string.

To solve your problem, you should: (i) point `locations` to the dataframe's index, and (ii) turn your GeoJSON string to a dictionary.

```py
import json

fig = go.Figure(
    go.Choroplethmapbox(
        geojson=json.loads(df_geo['geometry'].to_json()),  # convert to python object 
        locations=df_geo.index,  # point to dataframe's index
        z=df_geo['ALAND'],
        colorscale="Viridis", 
        zmin=df_geo['ALAND'].min(), 
        zmax=df_geo['ALAND'].max(), 
        marker_line_width=0
    )
)
```

[image]

**Notes**:

- When you turn a GeoDataFrame to json, it automatically uses the GeoDataFrame's index as the GeoJSON's ids. This is why you must point the `locations` argument to the frame's index.
- When you turn a GeoDataFrame to json it is saved as a string.